# High side driver IR2125

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver

I am currently attempting to construct an high side driver of Mosfet. There is scheme:
[image]

When there is no signal on IN pin:
HO = CS = Vs = 8.3 V.
When I send pulsing signal ( pwm like ) with 4 V amplitude I expect to see 11.4 V on HO and LOAD and 22 V on VB but it is not happens. There is still 8.3 V on HO, CS and Vs pins.

It seems like MOSFET can't open because Vgs = HO - CS = 0.
So, after that I connect Vs to ground and get Vs = CS = HO = 0 v while there is no signal on IN. But still nothing happens if send signal on IN.

Finally I get expected 11.0 V on LOAD and 21.0 V on VB using this method: disconnect Vs from GND same time high level signal on IN.

So, what I miss? How can I get Vcc on LOAD by using only IN pin? Is there is wrong scheme? I get it from datasheet. Explain me please.

Edit:
After modification of scheme:
[image]

I get expected 22 V on Vb and 11 V on Vs when 4 V on In. Is it correct scheme?

Comment: What power supply voltage are you using and what current can it supply?

Comment: I power it from 3 LiPo 3.7 v battery. I think it can supply current up to 2 A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you remember to run switching frequently? If you only switch once, the boost capacitor will discharge and there will not be enough voltage to hold the gate charged.

Comment: Yes, I use it in PWM driven application.

Comment: Do you have low side either? The source must go to GND potential.

Comment: I mean, with the pull down resistor the capacitor charges slowly, you have to really short this node to GND.

Comment: Did you mean that first scheme not will work without low side driver?

Comment: First- definitely, second- depends on resistor, but i bet you put like 1k or 10k,so the second one too.

Comment: I understood. I will try the first scheme in conjunction with a low-side driver. In the second scheme, I used 100 Ohm resistor, and it works.
Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Ok, so the frequency is low. Try higher frequency and it will stop working. And by the way, check to what voltage the boost capacitor charges. Maybe it's not enough to fully open the MOSFET.

Answer (score 1):

The second schematic (with load resistor) is better, as the load resistor is important for your high side driver to work.

During off state, the 100nF capacitor is charged, from current flowing through the diode and the load resistor.

As you turn on, the voltage at source rises, but so does the potential at the upper side of your capacitor and the high side driver is still able to further charge the gate capacitance until the FET is fully turn on.

If you want to use this circuit to create pulses you are fine, as on each pulse the 100nF capacitor will be recharged. You can't use  it to turn your FET on for a long time, as the 100nF capacitor will be finally drained (gate current leakage).

Comment: Great explanation! But I'm still confused by what did not work the first scheme! It is not workable or I did something wrong?

Comment: You need a load (the resistor in the second schematic) to charge the 100nF capacitor to Vcc.

Answer (score 1):

As well as the comments on the necessity of a low-side driver (or low-value load) and some duty cycle that it not 100% high for the bootstrap to work properly, this circuit will **never** work with a supply from a LiPo 3.7V battery.

In order to protect the MOSFETs from going into linear mode the [IR2125](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/ir2125.pdf) chip shuts down with less 9-10V supply. Many MOSFETs are specified with Vgs = 10V. This is called undervoltage lockout (UVLO) and is an important feature of MOSFET drivers.

[image]